# Deja-dup failing with "Host key verification failed"

Tags: ssh, backup, deja-dup

A remote ssh sever I use for backup recently changed its keys. I removed the relevant line from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, so I can log into it without any trouble. Deja-dup does not seem to take note of that and fails repeatedly complaining about the new key. I expect the problem is deja-dup has its own key cache, but I am not sure where that is stored. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and did some digging.

Deja-dup is a GUI frontend for duplicity, which uses paramiko on the backend.

Parakmiko uses ~/.ssh/known_hosts for its host-key verification.

Make sure that you can SSH in using the *same* hostname that is configured in Deja-dup. Being able to ssh directly to the server's IP isn't enough, you have to be able to ssh to the specific hostname as well. Use "ssh -F /dev/null server.name" to make sure your local config file isn't doing something weird.

After being able to ssh in to the same hostname declared in deja-dup-preferences, I was able to run "deja-dup --backup" without it complaining about the host-key.